# How to understand the requirement of `std::lower_bound`?

Tags: c++, c++11

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) about `std::lower_bound`, which says that:

> The range [first, last) must be partitioned ***with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)`***, i.e., all elements for which the expression is `true` must precede all elements for which the expression is `false`. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

I have a little difficulty to fully understand it.

1.What's `element < value`? It seems that `element` (or `value`) is never mentioned before this paragraph in the aforementioned document. Does the said `element` mean the elements before the current element, and the said `value` means the value of the current element?

***UPDATED***:

2.Since whether a specific sequence is valid(i.e. suits the requirement) or not depends the `value`, the requirement for a specific sequence could not be always be guaranteed when the value is different. I think it's meaningless to define such a requirement. It's seems that a fully sorted seuqence is more ***reliable*** and ****practical****.

Comment: Value is the argument in e.g. `( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value )`

Comment: And element is each element of the range; so you work on a sorted range, and you compare your input value against each element of the range until you find one element that is not smaller than the input value.

Comment: This information should be posted in a proper answer, not comments

Comment: @Passerby Thank you for the reply. But I don't agree with you. If what you said is right, then all the elements  of the container to be processed should be less than the `value` which is passed as an argument(since **the range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value`**). It's clear that the minimum of the elements of the container may be greater than `value`.

Comment: It basically means that a call of `lower_bound(begin, end, value)` where `begin` and `end` mark the beginning and (one past the) end of the range that you can pick some element in that range, such that all elements to the left (smaller index) are less than `value` and all elements to the right (larger index) are not.   So a range of `{3,2,4,5}` and another range of `{2,3,4,5}` (sorted) will both pass the criterion if value is `4`  (elements 0 and 1 are less than `4`, the rest are not).

Comment: @Peter If I understand you correctly, if the value if  `3`, the said range `i.e. {3,2,4,5}` is not valid anymore. If I am right, so whether a sequence is valid or not depends the `value`. Am I right?

Comment: @John - For some sequences, yes, validity depends on `value`.   For others there is no dependence on `value`  e.g. a container sorted in non-decreasing  order (for the version of `lower_bound()` that doesn't accept a predicate).

Comment: @Peter If I understand you correctly, the specific container has to be sorted in non-decreasing order to guarantee that there is no dependence on `value`. Am I right?

Comment: @John - I said that a sorted container guarantees that the behaviour of `lower_bound()` has no dependence on `value`.   I didn't say that is the only way to have no dependence on `value`  (because I don't know, and haven't had reason to check or work it out).   If you want such a guarantee, one approach is to sort first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's element < value

`value` is the parameter to `lower_bound`, see at the beginning of that page:

> template< class ForwardIt, class T > ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt
> first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );

The `value` in question is mentioned right here, the last parameter to the template. And `element`, references to some element and ***every*** element in the sequence.

This is rather a terse way to define the following: take every `element` in the sequence, one element at a time. When you do that, all elements for which the expression `element < value` returns true must appear in the sequence before all other elements, for which the same expression is false. It is explicitly intentional for the requirements to be defined in this manner, here's the explanation:

For example, if `value` is `4`, and we're talking about natural integers, here's one such sequence:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Here, all the elements for which this expression is true (1, 2, and 3), appear before all the elements for which this expression is false (4, 5, and 6).

The following sequence is also a valid sequence, in this case:

```
3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4
```

Here, same thing: 3, 2, and 1, for which the expression `element < 4` is true, appears before value 4, 5 and 6 for which the expression `element < 4` would be false. So, yes, this would ***also be a valid sequence*** for a call to `lower_bound` for the value of 4.

The following sequence will NOT be a valid sequence for this ***specific*** case of using `std::lower_bound`:

```
1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6
```

And as far as why is this `lower_bound` requirement specified in such an strange manner, well, that would be a different question. But this is what it means.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Some question about `3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4`. As you say `3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4` is a valid sequence, can I draw the conclusion that the sequence ***does not need to be a fully-sorted range*** to meet the requirement, although a fully-sorted range meets this criterion indeed? Am I right?

Comment: You are right. In short, *must be partitioned* means all elements that are less than `value` must be on the left side, all other elements (including `value`) must be on the right side of the range. A fully-sorted range satisfies this criteria but is not the only possible.

Comment: @273K I see. Thank you. So whether a sequence is valid or not depends the `value`. If the `value` is `4`, `{3,2,4,5}` is valid, whereas if the `value` is `2`, the said sequence is not valid any more. Am I right?

Comment: Well, actually, if the value is `2`, the `{3, 2, 4, 5}` sequence is also valid. All values that are less than 2, in this sequence, appear before the values that are not less than 2. The values that are less than 2 -- there happens to be none of them, appear before all the other values, which follow them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see, thank you. Since whether a sequence is valid or not depends the `value`, the requirement for a specific sequence could not be always be guaranteed when the `value` is different. I think it's meaningless to define such a requirement. It's seems that ***a fully sorted seuqence*** is more ***reliable*** and ***practical***. How do you think about it?

Comment: `std::lower_bound` is practically always used with fully sorted ranges. However, each individual call to `lower_bound` it is not required to have the range fully sorted. `lower_bound`'s technical specification simply gives the minimum requirements for using `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,
> last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last
> if no such element is found.
>
> The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the
> expression element < value or comp(element, value), i.e., all elements
> for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which
> the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

From your question:

> What's element < value? It seems that element (or value) is never
> mentioned before this paragraph in the aforementioned document. Does
> the said element mean the elements before the current element, and the
> said value means the value of the current element?

`value` and `comp` are mentioned in the function signatures at the beginning of the page. `value` is the argument with which you call `std::lower_bound`, and `comp` an optional comparison function; shouldn't a comparison function be provided, `<` would be used instead.

`element` refers to each element in the range `[first, last)`.

So, what `std::lower_bound` does is to compare `value` to the `element`s in the range until it finds the first one that is not "less than" (through `<` or `comp`) `value`.

The requirement for `std::lower_bound` to work is that the input range is partitioned in such a way that all the elements that are "less than"  `value` are placed before the rest; that requirement is met, for example, if the range is fully sorted.

(As @Passerby mentions in the comments below, `std::lower_bound` won't need to compare against all the elements that are "less than" `value`, due to the partitioned range requirement, but that is an implementation detail.)

Comment: `So, what std::lower_bound does is to compare value to each element in the range` This reads to me as if you mean it examines each element, is that really what you meant?

Comment: It checks `element < value`, or, if you provide a comparison function `comp`, it calls `comp(element, value)`; the `element < value` may be as simple as an `int` comparison, or as complex as calling `operator<` on two instances of a class.

Comment: My point is that I think your wording suggests that it examines all elements (first, second, etc.) If you look at the typical implementations, they are binary search. This enables some elements not to be examined.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the comment. I'll rephrase it. Considering the partition requirement, it wouldn't indeed be needed to check all of the elements.

Comment: @rturrado ***shouldn't a comparison function be provided, < would be used instead.***Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John `std::lower_bound` will use `<` by default as comparison function; if you're happy with that, you don't need to pass a comparison function; but it may be that you want to use `>` to compare your `int`s, or that you are comparing instances of class `A` for which `operator<` is not defined... in those cases, you'll have to pass a comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

#### Partitions

A list of values may be ***partitioned***, or grouped according to some ***criterion***. For example:

```
┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
|  2 |  7 |  3 | -5 | 11 | 94 | 15 | 12 |
└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
        x < 10      |       x ≥ 10
```

In this list we have two partitions:

- elements where x < 10
- elements where x is not < 10

Further, the criterion implies an order:

- all xs such that (x < 10) come —*before*— all xs such that !(x < 10)

(In C++ we tend to use a “comparator” or “comparison function” to specify the criterion.)

Notice that **it does not matter what order the elements are relative to each other in each partition!** That said, it is also noteworthy that if the list *were* sorted, it would still have the exact same two partitions:

```
┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
| -5 |  2 |  3 |  7 | 11 | 12 | 15 | 94 |
└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
        x < 10      |       x ≥ 10
```

(My example here has two equal-sized partitions. That is not necessarily the case. A partition may have zero or more elements, and each partition may have a different size than the others.)

#### Lower bound → index of start of partition

What the `lower_bound` algorithm does is find the *first* element of an existing partition.

The only caveat that the algorithm requires is that the sequence ***must** already be partitioned* in a way that the sort criterion makes sense. (Because the algorithm only *finds* partitions, it does not sort stuff!)

For example, our original sequence does *not* support a criterion that separates elements into (x < 7) and (x ≥ 7), because the elements are not partitioned in that way — it would not make sense to try to find the “first” element of a partition that doesn’t exist.

This is the meaning of the language used by cppreference.com.

Comment: ***comparitor or comparison function***?  What's comparitor?

Comment: In English, when you have “an _a_ is a _z_” phrase to define something, it is idiomatic to to add alternative names for _a_ as “an _a_ or a _b_ is a _z_”. — unless, of course, you are pointing out that I carelessly misspelled the thing...

Comment: Sorry, I am not native speaker.

Comment: Lol, no worries. That is what I thought might be the case. The fact that you do so well in English is actually _amazing_, so never apologize when asking for clarification. It helped because I _did_ misspell it, so I was at least able to fix that too...